# Jmeter HLS Plugin Error - master/slave configuration. Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,RMI Runtime] java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

when using the Jmeter Streamer Plugin (HLS Plugin) in a distributed setup (master/slave), I'm getting an error message an no tests are run. I have not issue when accessing a mpeg-dash live video stream without a distributed setup. Everything works fine. In a master/slave configuration I'm getting the following error:

```
2020-05-28 17:06:34,629 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,RMI Runtime]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.hls.logic.HlsSampler.testStarted(HlsSampler.java:234) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.testStarted(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1589) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:207) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:380) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Any ideas what the issue could be? The master/slave configuration seems to be ok, as i tried this successfully with a simple http-request sampler. I'm assuming the issue is related to the Streaming Plugin, but just assuming ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed with the v3.0.3 of the HLS Plugin. The Jmeter distributed test setup worked for me now. https://github.com/Blazemeter/HLSPlugin/issues/9